# What's wrong with this MySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, ddl, create-table

Alright so I'm trying to tie a Spigot plugin that I'm making into MySQL, and I did it successfully up until the point where I edited the code that was creating the table. I find that MySQL stack traces are much too ambiguous to be useful, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. 
Code:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WebsiteLink_keys(id INT NOT NULL KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, key VARCHAR(36), trimmedUUID VARCHAR(36), playerUUID VARCHAR(36), date TIMESTAMP, status TEXT);`

Comment: `key` and `date` are reserved words.  I wouldn't use them as column names, but if you do, you need to escape them with backticks (at least with `key`)...

Comment: @Sgeddes date is not a reserved word

Comment: @Strawberry -- Realized that after the post, but they are both keywords and I wouldn't recommend using either as column names.

Answer (score 2):

`key` is a reserved word in MySQL. If you absolutely must use it as a column name, you can escape it using backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WebsiteLink_keys (
    id INT NOT NULL KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `key` VARCHAR(36), -- Here!
    trimmedUUID VARCHAR(36), 
    playerUUID VARCHAR(36), 
    date TIMESTAMP, 
    status TEXT
)
```

Or, better yet, use a name that isn't a reserved word, such as `link_key`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WebsiteLink_keys (
    id INT NOT NULL KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    link_key VARCHAR(36), -- Here!
    trimmedUUID VARCHAR(36), 
    playerUUID VARCHAR(36), 
    date TIMESTAMP,
    status TEXT
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WebsiteLink_keys(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `key` VARCHAR(36), 
  trimmedUUID VARCHAR(36), 
  playerUUID VARCHAR(36), 
  `date` TIMESTAMP, 
  status TEXT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

PRIMARY KEY (id) is at the end